# Can't download searched tweets using Tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I've used the following script before but now it is not working. I don't see any tweets being printed in my terminal (as coded in line 38) nor are any tweets being stored in my csv. I don't what is the issue.

```
import tweepy
import csv
import time

access_token = "xxxxxxxxxx"
access_token_secret = "xxxxxxxxxx"
consumer_key = "xxxxxxxxxx"
consumer_secret = "xxxxxxxxxx"


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

print "Starting search..."

#
# Open/Create a file to append data
csvFile = open('somesearch.csv', 'a')
#Use csv Writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)


searchTerms = ["#Xfactor", "#Yfactor"]


tweets= tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=[searchTerms], \
                      since="2015-10-18",
                      until="2015-10-23",
                      include_entities=True).items(999999999)

#csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.id_str, tweet.screen_name, tweet.user_id, tweet.coordinates, tweet.place, tweet.text.encode('utf-8'), tweet.retweet_count, tweet.favorite_count])
#tweet.in_reply_to_user_id_str, tweet.in_reply_to_screen_name, tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str, tweet.retweeted, tweet.truncated, tweet.source

while True:
    try:
        for tweet in tweets:
            print tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')
            csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.id_str, tweet.author.name.encode('utf-8'), tweet.author.screen_name.encode('utf-8'),
                                tweet.user.location.encode('utf-8'), tweet.coordinates, tweet.text.encode('utf-8'), tweet.retweet_count, tweet.favorite_count])
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        time.sleep(60 * 15)
        continue
    except StopIteration:
        break

print "Done!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

```
tweets= tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=[searchTerms],
```

What you've done is created a list containing a list. Look at this code:

```
searchTerms = ["#Xfactor", "#Yfactor"]
q=[searchTerms]

print(searchTerms)
>>> ['#Xfactor', '#Yfactor']
print(type(q))
>>> [['#Xfactor', '#Yfactor']]
```

What you're searching for is not `searchTerms`, you're searching for a list of that.

So now the tweet you're interested for *must* contain the literal `['#Xfactor', '#Yfactor']`. To fix that issue change the `q` into:

```
tweets= tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=searchTerms,
```